# Azure Price API Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, api, rest, servicenow

we want to get price absed on all fields that are there in virtual machines. so do you have any specific API for virtual machines to get prices?
plus we want data of those fields so that we can use it to request from ServiceNow which is third party application. can we get data of those fields?

BR

Answer (score 0):

There is an [Azure Retail Prices API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices) that you can use to get the prices for all Azure Resources.

The various property names available are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/retail-prices/azure-retail-prices#api-property-details) and can be used in odata filters to get the prices for the resources that you need.